# Draft messages in Mountain Lion Mail do not include server draft messages

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, apple-mail

I had a clean install Mountain Lion on my Macbook Pro, early 2011.

Following suggestions in the forums, I carried my "Mail" folders (folders, preferences, etc) from my cloned backup of Snow Leopard.

Mountain Lion Mail automatically created the necessary accounts in the new way it is set up.

However, the local Drafts folders do not include my drafted messages in individual IMAP e-mail accounts (yahoo, gmail, uni, etc).

I can see these draf messages under the folders of these individual e-mail accounts. But they are not like drafts. I cannot edit them. I have same controls as in the messages that are sent to me.

on the other hand, if I open a new message, type somethings and close without sending, that message goes into the Drafts folder.

How can I go around this problem?

Comment: Are these folders recognized as Draft folders? Select *Mailbox » Use This Mailbox For » Drafts* in the menu. Note that you can select any email message and edit it for sending by selecting *Message » Send Again*.